# Exposed Elastic IP EC2 API times out from certain devices and works fine from others

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, vpc, elastic-ip

I have an API written in Go running on a t2.micro EC2 instance with Ubuntu server 18.04. I deployed this instance to a VPN in a public subnet, attached to an Elastic IP Address.

When I send HTTP requests from my desktop computer, which is on a wired ethernet connection, the API works as expected and returns a response. When I attempt it from my phone while connected to my apartment's wifi, it also works fine. However, on my university wifi network and cellular data, my requests time out, on both my laptop and phone.

I have tried using both the EIP IP address (#.#.#.#) and the equivalent DNS address (ec2-#-#-#-#.compute-1.amazonaws.com) with the same results. My immediate hunch is that this is related to DNS resolution somehow, but I have not had any success manually adding DNS servers to my network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not reachable via Elastic IP from university network and its accessible from home network.  Its due to Firewall rules set in organization, causing packet drop. You have to trace the route and check where its blocked (tracert/traceroute).

Also check Network ACL and Security Group setting of AWS, for the source subnets.